# ПРоблема со скриптом js и jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/).

И есть всплывающий блок

```js
$("#post").cleditor();
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function show_message(state){
    document.getElementById('window').style.display = state;   
    document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state;    
   }
   
</script>
<div onclick='show_message("none")' id='wrap'></div>
   <div id='window'>
    <div class='message_close' onclick='show_message("none")'></div><br>
    <form action='post' method='post'>
     <textarea rows='4' id='post' name='text'></textarea><br>
     <input type='hidden' name='poluchatel' value='$myrow[login]'>
     <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$myrow[id]'>
     <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Отправить'>
    </form>  
   </div>
  <center><div class='myButton' onclick='show_message("block")'>Написати листа</div></center>
```

(не работает потому что надо скрипт cleditor)

Если я `textarea` выпихиваю за блок, то все работает, а если он во всплывающем блоке, то он стает неактивным (просто серый, но скрипт активирован).

Comment: "Написати листа", - что это  значит?

Comment: @CoddWrench это украинский на руском значиь Написать письмо

Answer (score 0):

Может быть стоит использовать `jquery`, раз он уже есть в проекте?

Вот так получится:

**js:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#post").cleditor();
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $('#window').toggle();
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<div id='window'>
   <form action='post' method='post'>
      <textarea rows='4' id='post' name='text'></textarea><br>
      <input type='hidden' name='poluchatel' value='$myrow[login]'>
      <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$myrow[id]'>
      <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Отправить'>
   </form>
</div>
<center>
   <button id="button" class='myButton'>Закрыть/Открыть</button>
</center>
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurea9v1/)